# Use error_tag without the span or with a different class

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I use [Tailwind CSS 2.0](https://tailwindui.com) in a Phoenix application. The `error_tag` in a form gives me a headache:

```
<div>
  <label for="password" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
    Passwort
  </label>
  <div class="mt-1">
    <%= password_input f, :password, required: true, id: "password", type: "password", 
        autocomplete: "new-password", 
        class: "appearance-none block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md 
                shadow-sm placeholder-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 
                focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm" 
    %>
    <p class="mt-2 text-sm text-gray-500"><%= error_tag f, :password %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which results in this HTML:

```
<p class="mt-2 text-sm text-gray-500">
<span class="invalid-feedback" phx-feedback-for="user_password">
  should be at least 8 character(s)
</span>
</p>
```

and this rendering:

[image]

**Question:** Can I force `error_tag` not to render the `<span>`, use a different `class` or can I access the error message without the `error_tag`?

I tried to solve this by googling `error_tag` and `class` but that didn't result into any helpful article.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the implementation of [`error_tag/2`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/6605625065e2ea924bb0458335674756ad67ccdf/installer/templates/phx_web/views/error_helpers.ex#L11-L17)

```rb
def error_tag(form, field) do
  Enum.map(Keyword.get_values(form.errors, field), fn error ->
    content_tag(:span, translate_error(error),
      class: "invalid-feedback",
      phx_feedback_for: input_name(form, field)
    )
  end)
end
```

That said, I see many different approaches to handle the issue:

- use [`Phoenix.HTML.Tag.content_tag/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Tag.html?#content_tag/2) directly;
- overwrite CSS for `invalid-feedback` class to unset styles.

I would go with raw `content_tag/2`.

Answer (score 0):

Update the default error_helpers.ex file in your views directory to this:

```
def error_tag(form, field) do
Enum.map(Keyword.get_values(form.errors, field), fn error ->
  field = field |> Atom.to_string() |> String.capitalize()
  content_tag(:span, "#{field} #{translate_error(error)}", class: "block mt-1 text-sm text-red-700")
end) end
```

Fixed it for me and my error messages are displaying properly

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to change to a different class like this?

```
<%= error_tag f, class: "New class", :password %>
```